# push data from UITableView to view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, push, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push data from a tableView to a View controller. I can successfully transfer some of the data over, but I am still missing some key points. I will try to illustrate my question to the best of my abilities. In my notificationTableView, I have data that is stored such as a userName, userImage, jobName and jobImage. I can succesfully push over the users image and name, however The jobName and JobImage fails to be transferred over as we can see in the Images below.

[image: firstImage]

In this image, we can see the tableView sections that have the userName, userImage, jobName and jobImage.

[image: second image]

In the second image, we can see that the usersName, and Image is succesfully pushed. However, the jobImage and name are not transferred.

the code that I use to push over the information is

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let notification = notifications[indexPath.row]
    if notification.notificationType != .swipe {

        let acceptWorker = jobProgressViewController()
        acceptWorker.workerUser = myUser
        acceptWorker.workerUser = notification.user
        jobProgressView?.myParentViewController = self
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: acceptWorker)
                  present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
   print("something else should go here")
}
```

and the code that I use to retrieve the information is below. which is my jobProgressViewController

```
     var notification: userNotifications?
     var workerUser: User? {

didSet {
    let name = workerUser?.name
    workerNameLabel.text = name


    guard let profileImage = workerUser?.profileImageUrl else { return }
    workerImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImage)

    if let post = notification?.poster {
        jobImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(post.imageUrl1!)
        jobLabel.text = post.category
        addressLabel.text = post.category
                      }

}
}

   fileprivate func setupView(){
    let postUser = workerUser.self
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let userName = postUser?.name
    let posterId = postUser?.uid
    let post = notification?.poster

    guard let userImage = workerUser?.profileImageUrl else { return }
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        let user = User(dictionary: dictionary as [String : AnyObject])

        let currentUser = MyUser(dictionary: dictionary as [String : AnyObject])
        self.posterImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user")
        self.posterImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(userImage)

        self.userNameLabel.text = userName
        self.userNameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        self.userNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        self.workerImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user")
        self.workerImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(currentUser.profileImageUrl!)

        self.workerNameLabel.text = currentUser.name
        self.workerNameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        self.workerNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black


        self.addressLabel.text = postUser?.address
        self.addressLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        self.addressLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        self.jobLabel.text = post?.category
        self.jobLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        self.jobLabel.textColor = UIColor.black



    }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")

    })
     print("this is your uid \(posterId!)")
}
```

below is how I populate my notificationCell which shows the users information in my tableView

```
    var jobProgressView: jobProgressViewController? = nil

 var delegate: NotificationCellDelegate?

var notification: userNotifications? {
    didSet {


       guard let user = notification?.user else { return }
       guard let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl else { return }


        profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)
        configureNotificationLabel()
        configureNotificationType()

        if let post = notification?.poster {
            postImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(post.imageUrl1!)
        }
    }
}

    func configureNotificationLabel() {
    guard let notification = self.notification else { return }
    guard let user = notification.user else { return }
    guard let poster = notification.poster else { return }
    guard let username = user.name else { return }
    guard let notificationDate =  configureNotificationTimeStamp() else { return }
    guard let jobName = poster.category else { return }

    let notificationMessage = notification.notificationType.description

    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: username, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])

    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: notificationMessage , attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))

    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: jobName, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))

    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " \(notificationDate).", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]))
        notificationLabel.attributedText = attributedText
}
```

if there is anyInformation I may have left out to help with getting an answer please let me know. please and thank you.

Comment: I assume it does answer this question in a way, However, I am coding programmatically and these answers use xnibs or storyboards. I will try to dig through it more to see if I can find an answer that helps with my particular answer.

Comment: when `setupView` would be call in? I think in function `setupView` should binding data of workerUser to UI and call `setupView` in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: setupView is called in ViewDidLoad()

Comment: where did you set notification data to `jobProgressViewController`?

Comment: in my notificationView controller. is that what you are looking for?

Comment: bcz I see `jobProgressViewController` using notification data (`if let post = notification?.poster`) to show jobLabel and jobImage but I don't see where do you set.

Comment: @TraiNguyen where exactly do you see that?

Comment: I think the jobProgressViewController you are referencing is actually my notificationsCell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207560/discussion-between-trai-nguyen-and-zach-wilcox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discusstion, you forget set notification for `jobProgressViewController`

In func `didSelectRowAt indexPath` add below code:

```
acceptWorker.notification = notification
```